# Position controls side by side in dock mode

Tags: .net, vb.net, button, dock

[image]

I have here 2 buttons, dock at the bottom... But I want them side by side, not over and under. How can I do that?
I dock them because `WindowState = Maximize`. If I manually position them, they won't fill the space from left to right. I tried to use anchor, but it doesn't achieve what I want.

I want them like this even in full screen. thanks
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your Buttons into a [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

Create a `TableLayoutPanel` with two columns and one row. Set the size of each column to `50%`. Set the `Dock` property to `DockStyle.Bottom`.

Add a `Button` to each column. Set the `Dock` property of each `Button` to `DockStyle.Fill`.

Add this `TableLayoutPanel` to your `Form`/`Container` instead of the two Buttons directly:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the best way but it seems to do the job.

- Drag a SplitContainer on to your form then change its Dock property to Bottom.
- Drag your buttons into each side of the SplitContainer then change their Dock properties to fill.
- Customize the size of your SplitContainer.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you undock it you can change its size to whatever you want